# Confusion on how to use functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This is what I am trying to implement.

```
var globalVar = [];
var tomakeJson = JSON.Stringify(globalVar);
window.load = function grpwrk() {
   hdWork: function() {
        // return somefatherwork;
     };
   asstWork: function() {
       // return somemotherWork;
     };
};
```

To call a function

```
 globalVar.push(familyWork(hdWork()));
 globalVar.push(familyWork(asstWork()));
```

Then `tomakeJson` is send to backend server and gets stored in NoSQL.

Is this implementation right? Is there any other way to use this type of function?

Comment: This is so far from everything we know it's hard to get what you tried to do.  What's your goal ?

Comment: You have `JSON.Stringify(glovalVar)`, did you mean `globalVar`? Note `v` and `b`.

Comment: If you get what you expect , then it's right ...

Comment: @AkshayRahate The original code is not valid, you're mixing object literal syntax and function syntax.

Comment: You might want to get more familiar with [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)?

Answer (score 0):

This is some idea of code.

```
function StackHandler(){
    var stack = new Array();
    this.push = function(obj){
        return stack.push(obj);
    };
    this.pop = function(){
        return stack.pop();
    };
    this.getJSON = function(){
        return JSON.stringify(stack);
    };
};

var familyWork = {
    fatherWork : function(){
        // return somefatherwork;
    },
    motherWork : function(){
        // return somemotherWork;
    },
    broWork : function(){
        // return somebroWork;
    },
    sisterWork : function(){
        // return somesisterWork;
    }
};

var globalVar = new StackHandler();

globalVar.push(familyWork.fatherWork());
globalVar.push(familyWork.motherWork());
globalVar.push(familyWork.broWork());
globalVar.push(familyWork.sisterWork());

globalVar.getJSON(); // return JSON
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping JS arrays in another array like structure? That makes no sense to me. Also, if you're using a function as a constructor, the least you can do if you expect people to use it as such is abide to the convention that the first letter is capital.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't see how your whole `StackHandler` code gives me anything above using a native Array object though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think AkshayRahate want to use tomakeJson as function. So I just gave idea. If you have any good idea, please let me know. :)

Comment: This is how I'd write `StackHandler` if I had to http://jsfiddle.net/tbrDh/ . However, I really don't, JS arrays are extremely versatile, he's using JSON.stringify (and not a function of some custom object) in his original code too. PS, I did not down-vote.